# Regular Expression required for Selenium IDE - Object ID: dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_6_text

Tags: regex, selenium, ide

I am trying to generate a regex pattern for the Object ID: dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_6_text, the number in the id will change everytime i refresh or login, Selenium IDE is not able to identify the object. Can anyone generate the regex for this id and post it back.

Answer (score 1):

```
  better use xpath :


  type     //*[starts-with(@id, 'dijit_PopupMenuBarItem_')]       value
```